# Why do C enumeration constants need a name?

Tags: c

Why do C enumeration constants need a name? Because this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum {NO, YES};

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", YES);
}
```

works just the same as this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum boolean {NO, YES};

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", YES);
}
```

Comment: Please stop changing the name of your enumeration type - it means that our answers don't make sense!

Comment: heh e, you're too fast with the answers! ;p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create a type that is 'of the enum', such as:

```
enum boolean x;
x = NO;
```

The easier way to do this is with a typedef:

```
typedef enum {NO, YES} boolean;
```

And then all you have to do is use boolean as the type:

```
boolean x;
x = NO;
```

Answer (score 8):

So that you can create variables of the enumeration type:

```
enum boolean read_file = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you right you're simply using an example that is too basic.

[Days of the week](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/101/Lectures/EnumeratedTypes.html) is a good example of enums.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you might want to define a function like this:

```
void here_is_my_answer(boolean v)
{
   if (v == YES) { 
   } else {
   {
}
```