# Good use cases for declaring enum type tags and variable names in C?

Tags: c, enums, declaration

If you need some constants in your code you can declare them with enums:

```
enum {
    DOG,
    CAT,
    FISH,
};

enum {
    CAR,
    BUS,
    TRAIN,
};
```

and then use `DOG`, `BUS`, etc. as needed. But enums may be declared in a more verbose style as well:

```
enum animals {
    DOG,
    CAT,
    FISH,
} pets;

enum transport {
    CAR,
    BUS,
    TRAIN,
} vehicles;
```

Given that enum constants have global scope and cannot be referred by `pets.DOG` in the way that structs and unions can, are there any good use cases for the verbose style? To me the type tags and variable names for enums look quite redundant, even offputting as they look like structs but can't be used like structs. I hope I'm missing something and they do have a good use.

There is a related [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102542/how-to-define-an-enumerated-type-enum-in-c) where the overriding assumption is that one would use the type tags and variable names when using enums. So my question can be restated as "In what tasks would I fail if I use anonymous enums only?" Because to me, the whole point of enums are the `DOG`, `CAT`, `CAR` constants and I see no use for assigning one of these to an enum variable. I'm still learning, so I'm sure I must be missing something.

Comment: @Ctx Please clarify! As far as I understand and as far as my tests show, enum constants must have unique names. I don't understand what you're really referring to by "Two enums ... different values ... different contexts".

Comment: Ok, with enums this is indeed not possible

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question, but the reason you'd use an enum tag, is to be able to refer to it later (eg. to define a variable of the enum type) - ref. eg. [Why do C enumeration constants need a name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849895/why-do-c-enumeration-constants-need-a-name).

Comment: Or are you asking why you'd define enum type variables ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I'm asking for the useability of both, type and variables. As my question states, my impression is that enums are useful for the constants they declare. The constants are global and must be unique - so what's the use of type and variables? A full answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"To me the type tags and variable names for enums look quite redundant..."*

The value in using a sequential collection of named integer values in the form of an enumerated list ( `enum` ) might seem subtle at first glance, but becomes very apparent when used in C projects for a couple of reasons:

- The *names* associated with an enumerated list provide
  self-documenting code, i.e. particularly when collection of names
  chosen to represent a set of enumerated values forms a theme related
  to the task at hand.  (Your animal `enum` is a good example, as
  would be one used to enumerate eg. a large list of commands, or
  position types within a company.)
- The default assignment of values in an enumerated list are
  sequential, starting from 0, and increment by one until the end of
  the list, resulting in a list of unique values, very well suited for
  use when indexing through an array of strings with particular
  meaning, or when used in a `switch` statement as the constant integer
  value for each of the `case` statements.

And regarding comment: *"...but the advantage of using the `ANML` type instead of `int` is minimal,..."*

- `enum` lists also provide a documented *constraint*.  For example using `ANML anml;`
  rather than `int anml;` as a `struct` member will quickly indicate to those who will maintain/update the source code (In the months or years to come.) that there is an associated list of
  related values that this member is constrained to use, rather than
  any random integer value. This is important when an enumerated list
  will be used, eg. in a switch statement designed only to handle a set
  of `case` statements that correspond with the constant integer values in that `enum`.

These two together are part of the use-case I have found particularly useful i.e.  to use enumerations in conjucntion with string arrays for selecting content for user interface, or for sub-string search, etc.

eg:

```
typedef enum {
       CAT,
       DOG,
       FISH,
       MAX_ANML
    }ANML;//for use in struct

 char *strings[MAX_ANML] = {"cat","dog","fish"};

    typedef struct {
        char content[80];
        ANML anml;
    }SEARCH;
```

Where for example, the two constructs then can be used in conjunction with a `switch` statement:

```
bool searchBuf(SEARCH *animal)
{
    bool res = FALSE;
    switch (animal->anml) {
        case CAT:
            //use the string animal[type] for a search, or user interface content, etc.
            if(strstr(animal->content, strings[CAT]))
                res = TRUE;
            break;
        case DOG:
            if(strstr(animal->content, strings[DOG]))
                res = TRUE;
            break;
        case FISH:
            if(strstr(animal->content, strings[FISH]))
                res = TRUE;
            break;
    };
    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[] = {"this is a string containing cat."};
    SEARCH search;
    strcpy(search.content, buffer);
    search.anml = CAT;

    bool res = searchBuf(&search);
    //use res...

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looks very good and useful, but your code doesn't compile. Also, are you using enum type and variable names at all?

Comment: @ryyker Your code is very useful for demonstrating how a search may be constructed, but the advantage of using the `ANML` type instead of `int` is minimal: the name `anml` of the struct member makes intent sufficiently clear. I have now posted my own answer, and will wait for anything more persuasive.

Answer (score 3):

You can give `enum` types a name in case you want to declare variables of that type:

```
enum animals a1 = DOG;
enum animals a2 = CAT;
```

Or have them as function arguments:

```
void foo(enum animals a);
```

While enums are considered integer types, and you could also use an `int` to store one of these values, using a variable of an `enum` type helps to document your code and make you intent clear to the reader.

Comment: OK, so basically, I can get away with treating enum constants as ints, both for variable declarations and function arguments. The usefulness of enum type and variable is in their "commenting" property, signposting of intent. No more than that, right?

Comment: @Theo Some compilers also provide helpful warnings to avoid mistakes, like for example `enum animals a1 = TRAIN;`

Comment: @user694733 That's interesting, but does assume that I would have a reason to assign an enum constant to a particular enum variable. My question is why would I want to do that? After all, I'm declaring enums to get some ready constants, known by `DOG`, `TRAIN` etc. Why use the enum type and variable names at all?

Comment: @Theod'Or : a typical use of a variable is when you don't know the value at compile time (either because it's based on input, or a parameter to a function, or ...). This is true for all variables, including variables of enum type.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Please post a full answer that shows a failure due to not using enum type and variable name. Generic assertions about variables are not helping, particularly when the whole point of enums is that they serve as compile time constants, with global scope.

Comment: @Theod'Or : `42` is a compile-time constant with type `int` - does that mean it's not useful to have variables of the `int` type ? Now, substitute `DOG` for `42` and `enum animals` for `int`. You seem to be conflating different concepts and/or misunderstanding the concept of variables. Until I understand where your confusion lies though, I can't post an answer - I can only throw out bits of info that will hopefully trigger understanding.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Thank you for bearing with me, I appreciate it. I may be conflating concepts because the concepts are indeed conflated. When the whole point of defining enums is to define int constants, then I would use them as ints. I see no real reason beyond singposting of intent to use enum typenames and variable names. Hence my question - are there any stronger reasons than signposting of intent?

Comment: @Theod'Or : as mentioned by @user694733 above, some compilers will also produce "type safety" warnings for `enum` types when you accidentally get it wrong. That can be very useful. If you just use `int`, you won't get those. Even without those warnings, I consider it a lot clearer to see `enum animals` in code rather than just `int`, because then I *know* the code is working with an animal, and not just with any possible integer value. dbush's answer covers that.

Answer (score 0):

I like enums instead of #defines when I debug. The debuer shows me not only the numeric value, but also the enum name - very handy

Comment: By "enum name" are you referring to the enum constant such as `DOG` in my example, or the name of an enum variable the constant may be assigned to?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my own answer after a number of others have posted useful answers and comments, and we got as far as establishing that enum typenames and variable names are useful as self-documenting code and making the intent of the code clear (thanks to answers by ryyker and dbush).

As I was experimenting and looking for stronger reasons to use non-anonymous enums, I established that there cannot be any by definition. Enums have no scoping and bounds checks, not at compile time (GCC 6) nor at runtime. Here is a snippet demonstrating the weakness:

```
enum withType { // enum with type name and variable name
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE,
} wtEnum;

enum { // Anonymous enum
    TINY,
    SMALL,
    MID,
    LARGE,
    BIGGEST,
};

int main(void) {
    enum withType wt1 = LARGE; // Overflow!
    wtEnum = BIGGEST; // Overflow!
    printf("Enum test values: %d, %d, %d\n", THREE, wt1, wtEnum);
    return 0;
};
```

The example makes clear that any "scoping" you may want to do with enum type names and variable names is by convention only, and relies on coder discipline not to cross enum "domains". I would go so far as to claim that given this reality, enum functionality in C is "mis-designed". It creates the impression of the kind of utility we see with structs and unions, but provides nothing of the kind. After this insight, I consider anonymous enums the only safe enums to use!

All of that said, I have accepted ryyker's answer as it provides a nice demonstration of mainstream usage of enums. But I am leaving my own answer here as well, because the points I have raised are valid.

Comment: I typically always include a `MAX_` preface to the last value in an enumerated list, making the value of that last value == to the number of values in the list.  I do this particularly when I  plan to use it to create set ( array ) of strings corresponding to each `enum` value in the set.  (You may have noticed this in the code example of my answer

Comment: The two instances you have shown with `//Overflow!` comments, besides being very unlikely use cases, illustrate instances where the compiler warning should have been something to the effect: `warning: integer constant not in range of enumerated type 'enum with Type'`.  Which given the whole purpose of the `enum` type is a very appropriate, useful warning.  As has been stated several places around this post, Creating a ***range***  of integer constant values, with ***names***, usually of a theme, provides 1) self documenting code and 2) a way to...

Comment: ...enumerate a limited set of criteria, attributes, execution paths, etc. .

Comment: @ryyker Using the `//Overflow!` I wanted to demonstrate the lack of scoping of enums, an enum constant may be assigned to any enum. I didn't get the warning you mention, but then I only used `-Wall`. I'll look into the other options to enable the warning.

Comment: If you think about it, please post your findings, and tag me in a comment.  Most good compilers (gcc included) will warn on that usage.

Comment: @ryyker I have checked the GCC man page, and there are no options for the warning. The closest is `fsanitize=enum`, but that's part of runtime instrumentation options that would cause a runtime error, not compilation warning. Perhaps you were referring to another compiler. Also worth noting in the man page is that C++11 has scoped enums, exactly what C should have. I will try to contact Jens Gustedt who is active on SO and also part of C standard workgroup to ask about the possibility of scoping enums in C.

Comment: My Mistake on `GCC`, and I am surprised.  I use it often, but always in conjunction with CLANG and NI compilers.  The warning I quoted above (2nd comment) is an exact reproduction of what CLANG produced.  A similar warning is produced when I use the standard National Instruments compiler, with C99 extensions extensions turned on.  (And I verified these last two just a few minutes ago :) )